# Ruined Windows partition by formatting different partition

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I just wanted this easy, humble setup:

- SSD with dual boot (Ubuntu 18 + Windows 10)
- HDD with one data NTFS partition for double access from ubuntu and windows

I had my HDD with a triple boot in ubuntu 16 + kali + windows 7, so I bought a brand new SSD and there I installed the dual boot. So far so good, both OS's work perfectly.

Now I insert the HDD without having it formatted. I realize that, after doing some sudo apt update, I can see my old HDD partitions in GRUB and even initiate them. I can access all them without a problem, so I kept them just in case I needed something I had missed in the backup process.

I configure my ubuntu 18 partition and feel I am ready to format that HDD, so I open gparted and configure everything as follows:

[image: SDD description]

[image: HDD description]

And then, something terrible happened. Ubuntu could perfectly see my empty HDD, but Windows 10 was still seeing my previous partitions.

Shortly after this happening, I try to boot Windows 10, but it doesn't load.

I'm really sorry for not being able to show any more info of the process. Any help is welcome. Formatting again would mean three or four days of painfully restoring everything.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It's very likely you deleted the EFI partition that was being used to boot into Windows and Ubuntu, instead of creating it on the SSD, this is a common mistake people make when keeping the original installation on a HDD connected while reinstalling it.  You should be able to recreate the EFI partition with the appropriate command within WinRE

Answer (score 0):

What happened was the following.

After formatting the disk /sdb as a NTFS partition, I copied some 50Gb in it from Ubuntu! Apparently, Windows hates this, and when I extracted /sdb, the problem was no longer there.

The solution was just to format again /sdb, but this time as unallocated space and then format it as NTFS in Windows with the disk manager utility. Then copied those files from Windows.

It would be nice if someone could shed some light into why this is an issue with Windows.

Comment: Have you turned off fast startup in Windows?  Windows doesn't deal well with changing filesystem it can read when not fully shutdown and by default it doesn't.  You can turn fast startup (and hibernation) off with 'powercfg -h off'